# Horizontal scrolling divs after selecting content on dropdown

Tags: javascript, jquery, scroll

I'm trying to create a scoreboard where users can select the sport they're trying to view. I think I've got that part pretty well nailed down thanks to a search of this site -- but I would like to scoreboard to be able to scroll horizontally, as well. I'm having a hard time combining the two functions.

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/rcasey_chsaa/JSyLV/1602/) I've been working with.

And code:

```
    <div class="sport-select">Select sport:</div>
<div class="select-wrapper">
    <select id="selectMe">
        <option value="option1">Football</option>
        <option value="option2">Volleyball</option>
        <option value="option3">Softball</option>
        <option value="option4">Boys Soccer</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="option1" class="group">
    <div class="block">
        <table class="boxscore">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team A</td>
                    <td class="score">17</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team B</td>
                    <td class="score">14</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <table class="boxscore">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team C</td>
                    <td class="score">9</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team D</td>
                    <td class="score">0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <table class="boxscore">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team E</td>
                    <td class="score">15</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team F</td>
                    <td class="score">32</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <table class="boxscore">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team G</td>
                    <td class="score">28</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team H</td>
                    <td class="score">17</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <table class="boxscore">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team I</td>
                    <td class="score">18</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team J</td>
                    <td class="score">16</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <table class="boxscore">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team K</td>
                    <td class="score">30</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team L</td>
                    <td class="score">58</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <table class="boxscore">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team M</td>
                    <td class="score">84</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team N</td>
                    <td class="score">56</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <table class="boxscore">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team ABC</td>
                    <td class="score">40</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team 123</td>
                    <td class="score">51</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <table class="boxscore">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team MI</td>
                    <td class="score">4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team NW</td>
                    <td class="score">78</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <table class="boxscore">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team ERT</td>
                    <td class="score">9</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team QWERW</td>
                    <td class="score">54</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="option2" class="group">
    <div class="block">
        <table class="boxscore">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team O</td>
                    <td class="score">3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team P</td>
                    <td class="score">0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <table class="boxscore">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team Q</td>
                    <td class="score">3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team R</td>
                    <td class="score">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <table class="boxscore">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team S</td>
                    <td class="score">3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team T</td>
                    <td class="score">0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <table class="boxscore">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team U</td>
                    <td class="score">3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team V</td>
                    <td class="score">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <table class="boxscore">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team W</td>
                    <td class="score">3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team X</td>
                    <td class="score">0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="option3" class="group">
    <div class="block">
        <table class="boxscore">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team Y</td>
                    <td class="score">3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team Z</td>
                    <td class="score">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <table class="boxscore">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team AA</td>
                    <td class="score">4</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team BB</td>
                    <td class="score">2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <table class="boxscore">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team CC</td>
                    <td class="score">3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team DD</td>
                    <td class="score">2</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="option4" class="group">
    <div class="block">
        <table class="boxscore">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team EE</td>
                    <td class="score">3</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team FF</td>
                    <td class="score">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <table class="boxscore">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team GG</td>
                    <td class="score">0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team HH</td>
                    <td class="score">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
    <div class="block">
        <table class="boxscore">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team II</td>
                    <td class="score">0</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="team">Team JJ</td>
                    <td class="score">1</td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>
</div>
```

More code (drop-down):

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('.group').hide();
    $('#option1').show();
    $('#selectMe').change(function () {
        $('.group').hide();
        $('#' + $(this).val()).show();
    })
});
```

CSS:

```
.boxscore {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 9px;
    border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background: #fbfbfb;
    color: #333;
    display: inline-block;
}
.boxscore a {
    color:#1b76bc;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.team {
    padding: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #d8d8d8;
}
.score {
    padding: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #d8d8d8;
}
.info {
    padding: 2px;
    color:#333;
    background: #fbfbfb;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-top: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
}
.group {
    width: auto;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:55px;
}
.block {
    display: inline-block;
}
.select-wrapper {
    float:left;
    background: transparent;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 1;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 34px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    color: #333;
    font-family: verdana;
    clear: left;
}
.sport-select {
    float:left;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #333;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, Jeff. Is there a way to make it so a user can scroll via arrows, and not a scroll bar?

Comment: See my edited answer below. I hope it will suit your needs. You could change the small arrows by something more adequate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a container div around your `div.group` elements. You make the data move by modifying its `margin-left` attribute. See the JavaScript part.

Add the arrows:

```
<div id="tools">
    <span id="back">&lt;</span>
    <span id="spacer">&nbsp;</span>
    <span id="next">&gt;</span>
</div>
```

---

## [Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/lun471k/JSyLV/1610/)

---

### JavaScript

```
$('.group').hide();
$('#option1').show();
$('#selectMe').change(function () {
    $('.group').hide().css('margin-left', '0px');
    $('#' + $(this).val()).show();

});

$('#next').on('click', function () {
    console.log(parseInt($('.group').css('margin-left')));
    $('.group').css('margin-left', parseInt($('.group').css('margin-left')) + 10 + 'px');
});

$('#back').on('click', function () {
    console.log(parseInt($('.group').css('margin-left')));
    $('.group').css('margin-left', parseInt($('.group').css('margin-left')) - 10 + 'px');
});
```

### HTML

```
<div class="sport-select">Select sport:</div>
<div class="select-wrapper">
    <select id="selectMe">
        <option value="option1">Football</option>
        <option value="option2">Volleyball</option>
        <option value="option3">Softball</option>
        <option value="option4">Boys Soccer</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div id="groupContainer">
    <div id="option1" class="group">
        <div class="block">
            <table class="boxscore">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team A</td>
                        <td class="score">17</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team B</td>
                        <td class="score">14</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <table class="boxscore">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team C</td>
                        <td class="score">9</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team D</td>
                        <td class="score">0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <table class="boxscore">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team E</td>
                        <td class="score">15</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team F</td>
                        <td class="score">32</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <table class="boxscore">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team G</td>
                        <td class="score">28</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team H</td>
                        <td class="score">17</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <table class="boxscore">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team I</td>
                        <td class="score">18</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team J</td>
                        <td class="score">16</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <table class="boxscore">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team K</td>
                        <td class="score">30</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team L</td>
                        <td class="score">58</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <table class="boxscore">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team M</td>
                        <td class="score">84</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team N</td>
                        <td class="score">56</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <table class="boxscore">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team ABC</td>
                        <td class="score">40</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team 123</td>
                        <td class="score">51</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <table class="boxscore">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team MI</td>
                        <td class="score">4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team NW</td>
                        <td class="score">78</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <table class="boxscore">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team ERT</td>
                        <td class="score">9</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team QWERW</td>
                        <td class="score">54</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="option2" class="group">
        <div class="block">
            <table class="boxscore">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team O</td>
                        <td class="score">3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team P</td>
                        <td class="score">0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <table class="boxscore">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team Q</td>
                        <td class="score">3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team R</td>
                        <td class="score">1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <table class="boxscore">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team S</td>
                        <td class="score">3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team T</td>
                        <td class="score">0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <table class="boxscore">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team U</td>
                        <td class="score">3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team V</td>
                        <td class="score">1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <table class="boxscore">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team W</td>
                        <td class="score">3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team X</td>
                        <td class="score">0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="option3" class="group">
        <div class="block">
            <table class="boxscore">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team Y</td>
                        <td class="score">3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team Z</td>
                        <td class="score">1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <table class="boxscore">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team AA</td>
                        <td class="score">4</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team BB</td>
                        <td class="score">2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <table class="boxscore">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team CC</td>
                        <td class="score">3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team DD</td>
                        <td class="score">2</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="option4" class="group">
        <div class="block">
            <table class="boxscore">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team EE</td>
                        <td class="score">3</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team FF</td>
                        <td class="score">1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <table class="boxscore">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team GG</td>
                        <td class="score">0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team HH</td>
                        <td class="score">1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="block">
            <table class="boxscore">
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team II</td>
                        <td class="score">0</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="team">Team JJ</td>
                        <td class="score">1</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr>
                        <td class="info" colspan="2">Final</td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
<div id="tools"><span id="back">&lt;</span><span id="spacer">&nbsp;</span><span id="next">&gt;</span>
</div>
```

### CSS

```
.boxscore {
    font-family: verdana;
    font-size: 9px;
    border: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
    border-collapse: collapse;
    background: #fbfbfb;
    color: #333;
    display: inline-block;
}
.boxscore a {
    color:#1b76bc;
    text-decoration: none;
}
.team {
    padding: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #d8d8d8;
}
.score {
    padding: 2px;
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #d8d8d8;
}
.info {
    padding: 2px;
    color:#333;
    background: #fbfbfb;
    font-weight:bold;
    border-top: 1px solid #d8d8d8;
}
#groupContainer {
    width:450px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.group {
    width:450px;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:55px;
}
.block {
    display: inline-block;
}
.select-wrapper {
    float:left;
    background: transparent;
    width: 100px;
    padding: 5px;
    font-size: 10px;
    line-height: 1;
    border: 0;
    border-radius: 0;
    height: 34px;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    color: #333;
    font-family: verdana;
    clear: left;
}
.sport-select {
    float:left;
    font-size: 10px;
    color: #333;
    font-family: verdana;
    font-weight: bold;
    padding-left: 5px;
}
#tools {
    margin-left:125px;
}
#spacer {
    display:inline-block;
    width:400px;
}

#tools {
    cursor:default;
    user-select:none;
    -moz-user-select:none;
    -webkit-user-select:none;
}
#back, #next {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

Comment: Jeff, that's it! Thank you, you were very helpful. I greatly appreciate it. The only change I made is getting rid of `overflow: hidden` in my `.group` container so that I can scroll through all the scores. Again, thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The scrolling is done in the wrapper styles:

```
.group {
    width: 300px;
    height: 77px;
    white-space: nowrap;
    overflow: auto;
}
```

You can make arrows scroll the wrapper pretty simply using jQuery:

```
var scrollInterval;

function scrollDiv(px){
    var visGroup = $('.group:visible');
    visGroup.scrollLeft(
        visGroup.scrollLeft() + px
    );
};

//Scroll arrows
$('#arrowR').mousedown(function(){
    scrollInterval = setInterval(function(){ scrollDiv(10) }, 50);
});
$('#arrowR').mouseup(function(){
    clearInterval(scrollInterval);
});
$('#arrowL').mousedown(function(){
    scrollInterval = setInterval(function(){ scrollDiv(-10) }, 50);
});
$('#arrowL').mouseup(function(){
    clearInterval(scrollInterval);
});
```

Updated jsFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JSyLV/1612/